# Workflow tasks not visible in My Tasks list

Tags: workflow, 2013, groups, publishing, content-approval

I am using standard Publishing workflow on one of my list. I have two users in "Approvers" group and this group is added to this workflow.

I have deselected the Expand Groups option which says "For each group entered, assign a task to every individual member and to each group that it contains" so that any one person can approve the workflow and it will stop.

But due to this now I have run into another issue and that is workflow tasks are not showing up in user's My Task list. If I check the above option then they show up in My Task list but then each user has to approve workflow before it stops which I don't want.

- I want My Task list to show task to each user in that group
- I want to make sure that any one person can approve workflow and then it will stop

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it by adding another filter in view of My Tasks that also show when "Assigned To" is equal to "Approvers" group.